# Project not opening when I open solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution with multiple projects.  One of them is not opening when I open the solution.  I'm not sure why it doesn't open along with the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have some framewrok installed on your machine? Like if you had a web project on mvc3 and .net framework 4 you would have to have them installed.

Please be more specific about your project and give more details

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't open with the solution anymore when it used to.  I right clicked on the solution in solution explorer and added it to the solution.